# Opening Youtube e-mail attachments

Tags: youtube

How do I open You Tube video from link in Thunderbird e-mail attachment?

Comment: Try Ctrl+click, or double click

Answer (score 1):

You can find the settings here:

- Open TB
- Click 'Edit'
- Click 'Preferences'
- Click 'Attachments' tab
- You will see 'Content Type' listed (mine shows 'http' and 'https')
- Under 'Action' select 'Use Other'
- Locate the browser you want to use (usually in /usr/lib/)
- Repeat for both 'Content Types'
- 'Action' should now read 'Use [your browsername]'
- Close. You're all set.